# Apply materials to every other object in Unity using code

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spawn 8 quads in a row and then assign a material to every other quad, so it would look like a checkerboard pattern. The code I have accomplishes that, but I was wondering if there was a way to simplify it. So if I were to create more quads in different positions (for example, I wanted to create a row above the one I've already created), I wouldn't have a long list of repetitive code.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        quad.transform.position = new Vector3(i * 1, 0, 0);

        if (i == 1)
        {
            MeshRenderer mesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
        }

        if (i == 3)
        {
            MeshRenderer mesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
        }

        if (i == 5)
        {
            MeshRenderer mesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
        }

        if (i == 7)
        {
            MeshRenderer mesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
        }

        else
        {
            MeshRenderer mesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Bone");
        }

    }
```

My code checks to see if the position of the quad is equal to 1, 3, 5 or 7, and applies my material, then it uses another material of mine to fill the quads that aren't in those positions.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check if `i` is odd. If it is then paint it with charcoal. Something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
    quad.transform.position = new Vector3(i * 1, 0, 0);
    MeshRenderer mesh = quad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();        
    if (i%2 != 0) // if i is odd
    {
        mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
    } else // if i is even
    {
        mesh.material = (Material)Resources.Load("Bone");
    }
}
```

Comment: For this problem in particular even and odd will do the trick easily. More materials would mean a refactoring, and in that case OP could start thinking about a better way to do it, and even then, assuming 3 materials, he could use divisible by 3 logic and it would still work.

Answer (score 2):

Create Gamobject Prefab **Quad** and add empty gameobject in scene with adding script **board** Now assign this Quad prefab to board script public gameobject then run it in unity and it will generate the checker board as well considering even/odd logic

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class board : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public GameObject quad;
void Start () {
    for(int j=-4;j<4;j++)
    {
        for(int i=-4;i<4;i++)
        {
            var gameObject=Instantiate(quad,new Vector3(i,j,0),Quaternion.identity);

            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = (Material)Resources.Load("bone");
                else
                    gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
            }
            else
            {
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                    gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = (Material)Resources.Load("bone");
                else
                    gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = (Material)Resources.Load("Charcoal");
            }
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Resulting scene assign prefab as
[image]

**Output Result checker**

[image]